# Migrate: createStub() method not being invoked

Tags: taxonomy-terms, migrations

I'm trying to use Migrate to import some stuff from a database into terms on a site. The terms might be hierarchal, so I'm trying to [create stubs for the possible parents](https://www.drupal.org/node/1013506). However, my createStub() method doesn't ever seem to be invoked, and if I check in a prepareRow() method, I'm still seeing the source database's IDs. Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong here?

```
<?php
class AlbrightsCoolTermMigration extends Migration {
  public function __construct($arguments) {
    // …
    $this->addFieldMapping('parent', 'ParentId')
      ->sourceMigration(array($this->getMachineName()));
  }

  public function createStub(Migration $migration, array $source_id) {
    error_log(print_r($source_id, TRUE)); // This never fires
    static $vid = NULL;
    if (!is_numeric($vid)) {
      $vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('product_category');
      $vid = $vocab->vid;
    }
    $term = (object) array(
      'vid' => $vid,
      'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'product_category',
      'name' => 'stub',
    );
    taxonomy_term_save($term);
    return array($term->tid);
  }
}
```

?>

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Wondering if you found a solution?